# Renaming a .txt file after outsheeting it

Tags: text-files, stata, file-rename

I create a .txt file by outsheeting it.  As crazy as this sounds, I am wondering whether I can then, in Stata, rename that .txt file?  Or, alternatively, could I assign the first one a temporary name?

The situation is that I would ideally like to have a .txt file created and named in as short of a period of time as possible.  Normally, I'm sure in the outsheeting the file is gradually created.

I use Windows XP to run Stata.

I have the outsheet line.  Can there be a line after it like:

```
shell ren fileoutsheeted.tmp fileoutsheeted.txt
```

Comment: Renaming it and assigning the first file a temporary name seem like the same thing to me. Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to do. Why do you think this will be faster?

Comment: My motivation is that the process of outsheeting is likely slower than the process of renaming a file.

Comment: For any substantial amount of data outsheeting will be slower, but with this method you both outsheet and rename, instead of just outsheeting to the name you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, and that is to run the command line code to rename a file in your given operating system from Stata using the `shell` or `!` command. What operating system are you on?

In Windows it would look something like:

```
!ren "C:/Path/to/myfile/oldname.txt" "C:/Path/to/myfile/newname.txt"
```

And for Unix systems it would be

```
!mv "/usr/local/path/to/myfile/oldname.txt" "/usr/local/path/to/myfile/newname.txt"
```

Comment: I edited my question to make clear that I use Windows.  Can I put this within a .do file?  I have the one line that outsheets.  Then, can I immediately rename on the next line within the .do file?

Comment: Give it a try! This should work fine in a do file. Is there something that makes you think it might not? Perhaps I can answer to that specific concern

Answer (score 1):

This is totally unnecessary, on a level with "I want to call you Bill, but I will call you Fred first and then I will change your name".

Give the file the name you want at the outset on the `outsheet` command. Clearly, you must supply a name at that point.

The shell call  to rename the file can't be done in zero time, a proof that naming it just once is fastest.

It may well be correct that creating the file takes a while, but that's true either way.

Comment: This seems to me a completely different question.

Comment: The sane thing for Stata to do is not to release a file for reading while Stata is still writing. If you think that you have evidence for Stata behaving differently, it's best posed as a new question.

Comment: If you use the technique I described in your other question, it is Stata itself that calls the perl script. Stata won't call the perl script until it's finished the command to write the file, so you don't have to worry